# How to determine why SQL Server 08 stopped running

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 Standard instance running under Windows Server 2008 Standard.  The SQL Server service is configured to start automatically (under the Network Service account); but occasionally when I come in to work and try to run something that uses the DB I discover that it's not running.

What do I need to look at to find out why it's either shutting down or not restarting after IT reboots the VM?

Comment: Queue the Ren & Stimpy "Log Song".

Comment: @Tim is that something I should refrain from Googling until I'm home and don't have big brother monitoring my HTTP traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event logs will probably be your best place to start.  There should be at the very least service start/stop logs.

Comment: What do I look under to filter the logs down to something reasonable?  SqlServer isn't listed under Applications and Service Logs-Microsoft, and the Filter Current Log dialog doesn't appear to have anywhere I can enter plaintext to search for events mentioning MSSQLSERVER in the general field.

Comment: look for mssql or the instance name of your sql server.

Comment: Where?  I was able to find the startup event since I remembered roughly when I did so, but nothing in the default listview row (Information; 12/12/2011... ; Service Control Manager Event;7036;None) is enlightening.  I tried adding the keyword column but "Classic" isn't helpful either.

Comment: I just right click the application log click find & search for mssql.

Comment: My context menu choices are:  Open Saved Log, Create Custom View, Import Custom View, and Help.  CCV gives me a dialog with lots of checkboxes and dropdowns but no text field to enter mssql into.  Am I clicking in the right place?

Comment: For the 2nd time... right click the "Application" log... not the "Windows Logs" folder.  Click on the "Find..." option... and type "mssql" in the little dialog that pops up.  http://imagebin.org/188213

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1970/discussion-between-dan-neely-and-thecompwiz)